# Why is my form selection box not toggling items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form selection box, the code has worked before but it does not seem to work now, please can someone help me find where the error is

Basically I have a form with the #main and a selection box called #chart-type. what I need the #chart-type select box do is show/hide a selection of divs as needed. As mentioned before it has worked in the past. I have a Javascript code that hides all unecessary divs onLoad but I have never had issue with this before hiddning these permanently. The divs that are hidden will contain charts, they are currenly just grey blocks for now for coding purposes.

You help is greatly appreciated.

The Divs to be hidden

```
<div id="chartdiv1" style="width:100%; height:600px"></div>
<div id="chartdiv2" style="width:100%; height:600px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV2 - EURO CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv3" style="width:100%; height:600px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV3 - GBP CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv4" style="width:100%; height:600px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV4 -  ZAR CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv5" style="width:100%; height:600px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV5 - USD PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
<div id="chartdiv6" style="width:100%; height:600px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV6 - EURO PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
<div id="chartdiv7" style="width:100%; height:600px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV7 - GBP PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
<div id="chartdiv8" style="width:100%; height:600px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV8 - ZAR PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
```

The form code

```
<form class="main" id="main">
Chart Type: 
<select id="chart-type" class="unit-price" >
<option value="unit-price1" id="unit-price1">Unit Price in US Dollars</option>
<option value="unit-price2" id="unit-price2">Unit Price in Alternative Currency</option>                    
<option value="unit-price3" id="unit-price3">Unit Price Performance over a Period</option>
</select>

<span id="hidden">Alternative Currency:</span> 
<select id="currency" class="unit-price-period" >
                    <option value="GSO_USD" id="GSO_USD">GSO_USD</option>
                    <option value="GSO_EUR" id="GSO_EUR">GSO_EUR</option>
                    <option value="GSO_GBP" id="GSO_GBP">GSO_GBP</option>
                    <option value="GSO_ZAR" id="GSO_ZAR">GSO_ZAR</option>
                </select>
            <span id="hidden2">Alternative Currency Period:</span> 
            <select class="unit-price-period" id="currency2">
                    <option value="GSO_USD1" id="GSO_USD1">GSO_USD</option>
                    <option value="GSO_EUR1" id="GSO_EUR1">GSO_EUR</option>
                    <option value="GSO_GBP1" id="GSO_GBP1">GSO_GBP</option>
                    <option value="GSO_ZAR1" id="GSO_ZAR1">GSO_ZAR</option>
            </select> 
  </form>
```

The Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $( '#main' ).change( function() {
        var $select = $( '#chart-type' ),
        selected = $select.val();
        if ( selected == "unit-price1" ) {
        $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).show();
            chart1.invalidateSize();
        } else {
            $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).hide();
        }
        });

        $( '#main' ).change( function() {
        var $select = $( '#chart-type' ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "unit-price2" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv2, #hidden, #currency' ).show();
        } else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv2, #hidden, #currency' ).hide();

        }
        });
    $( '#main' ).change( function() {
            var $select = $( '#chart-type' ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "unit-price3" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv3, #hidden2, #currency2' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv3, #hidden2, #currency2' ).hide();
        }
    });
    });
    function hide() {
    var show = ['chartdiv1'];
    for ( var i = 0; i < show.length; ++i ) 
    document.getElementById(show[i]).style.display = "block";
    var hide = ['chartdiv2','chartdiv3','chartdiv4','chartdiv5','chartdiv6','chartdiv7','chartdiv8','hidden','hidden2','currency','currency2'];
    for ( var i = 0; i < hide.length; ++i ) 
    document.getElementById(hide[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Can you please make js fiddle of your code?

Comment: Hi seems to work in the JSfiddle weird, except for the ppure Javascript part, not sure to set onLoad in JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jason1975/xz636ghm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Check what Zakaria talks about in his answer.
then you can try this :

#### HTML

```
    <form class="main" id="main">
    Chart Type:
    <select id="chart-type" class="unit-price">
        <option value="" id="">-- Select Price --</option>
        <option value="unit-price1" id="unit-price1">Unit Price in US Dollars</option>
        <option value="unit-price2" id="unit-price2">Unit Price in Alternative Currency</option>
        <option value="unit-price3" id="unit-price3">Unit Price Performance over a Period</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <span id="hidden">Alternative Currency:</span>
    <select id="currency" class="unit-price-period">
        <option value="GSO_USD" id="GSO_USD">GSO_USD</option>
        <option value="GSO_EUR" id="GSO_EUR">GSO_EUR</option>
        <option value="GSO_GBP" id="GSO_GBP">GSO_GBP</option>
        <option value="GSO_ZAR" id="GSO_ZAR">GSO_ZAR</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <span id="hidden2">Alternative Currency Period:</span>
    <select class="unit-price-period" id="currency2">
        <option value="GSO_USD1" id="GSO_USD1">GSO_USD</option>
        <option value="GSO_EUR1" id="GSO_EUR1">GSO_EUR</option>
        <option value="GSO_GBP1" id="GSO_GBP1">GSO_GBP</option>
        <option value="GSO_ZAR1" id="GSO_ZAR1">GSO_ZAR</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="chartdiv1" style="width:100%; height:60px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV1 - CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv2" style="width:100%; height:60px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV2 - EURO CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv3" style="width:100%; height:60px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV3 - GBP CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv4" style="width:100%; height:60px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV4 - ZAR CURRENCY</div>
<div id="chartdiv5" style="width:100%; height:60px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV5 - USD PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
<div id="chartdiv6" style="width:100%; height:60px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV6 - EURO PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
<div id="chartdiv7" style="width:100%; height:60px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV7 - GBP PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
<div id="chartdiv8" style="width:100%; height:60px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV8 - ZAR PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div>
```

#### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#main').change( function() {
    var $select = $('#chart-type'),
    selected = $select.val();
    switch (selected){
        case "unit-price1" :
            $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).show();

            $( 'div#chartdiv2, #hidden, #currency' ).hide();
            $( 'div#chartdiv3, #hidden2, #currency2' ).hide();
            break;
        case "unit-price2" :
            $( 'div#chartdiv2, #hidden, #currency' ).show();

            $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).hide();
            $( 'div#chartdiv3, #hidden2, #currency2' ).hide();
            break;
        case "unit-price3" :
            $( 'div#chartdiv3, #hidden2, #currency2' ).show();

            $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).hide();
            $( 'div#chartdiv2, #hidden, #currency' ).hide();
            break;
        default : "";
    }

});
function hide() {
  var show = ['chartdiv1'];
  for ( var i = 0; i < show.length; ++i ) 
     document.getElementById(show[i]).style.display = "block";
  var hide = ['chartdiv2','chartdiv3','chartdiv4','chartdiv5','chartdiv6','chartdiv7','chartdiv8','hidden','hidden2','currency','currency2'];
  for ( var i = 0; i < hide.length; ++i ) 
      document.getElementById(hide[i]).style.display = "none";
}
});
```

I've made some style modification just to display it correctly on jsfiddle.

You can test it yourself on : http://jsfiddle.net/v14pLfnb/
And if you have any question don't hesitate.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks Ben, turns out the code does work, working in a clean enviroment. Think there is some code in the main webpage that is conflicting which I will find. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify if you have this error in the navigator console :

```
ReferenceError: chart1 is not defined
in chart1.invalidateSize();
```

Fix that maybe  solve the probleme.

Comment: Thanks Zakaria, turns out the code does work, working in a clean enviroment. Think there is some code in the main webpage that is conflicting which I will find. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Hi Zakaria this post and my new one are related. I have created a js fiddle in the next one can you see if you can help me here. the address for post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395907/how-would-i-clear-the-content-of-a-previous-form-entry-with-jquery?noredirect=1#comment43250062_27395907   ma