# How would I clear the content of a previous form entry with JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am busy Implementing a flow form where it show and hides divs as needed.

onLoad all divs are hidden except for chartdiv1 and the initial selection.

Selection Options
1) Unit Price in US Dollars - really just keeps chartdiv1 there
2) Unit Price in Alternative Currency - Brings in chartdiv2 + an additional dropdown (#currency) allowing for additonal Chartdivs to be brought in (all initally hidden).
3) Unit Price Perfomance over a Period - Brings in chartdiv5 + additional dropdown(#currency2) hiding the previous dropdown, This allows for additonal divs to be selected date.

The problem I am have is that the last clicked divs in these additional dropdown are not clearing and I end up have two divs showing at the same time. how can I manipulate my JQUERY code to make the divs clear once the other slections are made in the main dropdown

I have attached my JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jason1975/9jz8pjwy/ to show this, I do apologise though I am new to JSfiddle and do not know how to add my Body onLoad="hide()" function in it show all the divs are showing currently, some help with that would also be great.

HTML Code

```
<form class="main" id="main">
                Chart Type: 
                <select id="chart-type" class="unit-price" >
                    <option value="unit-price1" id="unit-price1">Unit Price in US Dollars</option>
                    <option value="unit-price2" id="unit-price2">Unit Price in Alternative Currency</option>                    <option value="unit-price3" id="unit-price3">Unit Price Performance over a Period</option>
                </select>
                <span id="hidden">Alternative Currency:</span> 
                <select id="currency" class="unit-price-period" >
                    <option value="GSO_EUR" id="GSO_EUR">GSO_EUR</option>
                    <option value="GSO_GBP" id="GSO_GBP">GSO_GBP</option>
                    <option value="GSO_ZAR" id="GSO_ZAR">GSO_ZAR</option>
                </select>
            <span id="hidden2">Alternative Currency Period:</span> 
            <select id="currency2" class="unit-price-period">
                    <option value="GSO_USD1" id="GSO_USD1">GSO_USD</option>
                    <option value="GSO_EUR1" id="GSO_EUR1">GSO_EUR</option>
                    <option value="GSO_GBP1" id="GSO_GBP1">GSO_GBP</option>
                    <option value="GSO_ZAR1" id="GSO_ZAR1">GSO_ZAR</option>
            </select>
            </form><br /><br />
            <div id="chartdiv1" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV1 - USD CURRENCY</div><br />

    <div id="chartdiv2" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV2 - EURO CURRENCY</div><br />

    <div id="chartdiv3" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV3 - GBP CURRENCY</div><br />

    <div id="chartdiv4" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV4 -  ZAR CURRENCY</div><br />
    <!-- End Chartdiv3 -->
    <!-- Chartdiv5 - USD Unit Price Perfomance over a Period -->
    <div id="chartdiv5" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV5 - USD PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div><br />

    <div id="chartdiv6" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV6 - EURO PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div><br />

    <div id="chartdiv7" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV7 - GBP PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div><br />

    <div id="chartdiv8" style="width:100%; height:250px; background: #CCC">CHARTDIV8 - ZAR PERFORMANCE PERIOD</div><br />
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY

```
 // MENU TOGGLE SCRIPTS
    // Menu Toggle Script 1 - Working
    $(document).ready(function() { 
hide();
    $( '#chart-type').change( function() {
        var $select = $( this ),
        selected = $select.val();
        if ( selected == "unit-price1" ) {
        $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).show();
        } else {
            $( 'div#chartdiv1' ).hide();
        }
        });
        $( '#chart-type' ).change( function() {
        var $select = $( this ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "unit-price2" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv2, #hidden, #currency' ).show();
        } else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv2, #hidden, #currency' ).hide();

        }
        });
    $( '#chart-type' ).change( function() {
            var $select = $( this ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "unit-price3" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv5, #hidden2, #currency2' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv5, #hidden2, #currency2' ).hide();
        }
    });
    // Menu Script 2
    $( '#currency' ).change( function() {
            var $select = $( this ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "GSO_EUR" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv2' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv2' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( '#currency' ).change( function() {
            var $select = $( this ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "GSO_GBP" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv3' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv3' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( '#currency' ).change( function() {
            var $select = $( this ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "GSO_ZAR" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv4' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv4' ).hide();
        }
    });
    // Menu Script 3
    $( '#currency2' ).change( function() {
            var $select = $( this ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "GSO_USD1" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv5' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv5' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( '#currency2' ).change( function() {
            var $select = $( this ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "GSO_EUR1" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv6' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv6' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( '#currency2' ).change( function() {
            var $select = $( this ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "GSO_GBP1" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv7' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv7' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $( '#currency2' ).change( function() {
            var $select = $( this ),
            selected = $select.val();
            if ( selected == "GSO_ZAR1" ) {
            $( 'div#chartdiv8' ).show();
        }  else {
        $( 'div#chartdiv8' ).hide();
        }
    });
    });
    function hide() {
    var show = ['chartdiv1'];
    for ( var i = 0; i < show.length; ++i ) 
    document.getElementById(show[i]).style.display = "block";
    var hide = ['chartdiv2','chartdiv3','chartdiv4','chartdiv5','chartdiv6','chartdiv7','chartdiv8','hidden','hidden2','currency','currency2'];
    for ( var i = 0; i < hide.length; ++i ) 
    document.getElementById(hide[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: call your hide(); method after your document.ready line.

Comment: hi Suchit the <body onLoad="hide()" function does work in the actual HTML page. I just do not know who to set it in JSFiddle. my main issue lies with with the main dropdown not clearing the last div of additional dropdowns.

Comment: I think that what @suchit meant is, after $(document).ready(function() { .... you should be writing hide();

Comment: hi added the hide(); method after the function in both my question and my jsfiddle, I am quite new at developing so I have to ask must I out the selector divs in to. Thanks again for the help.